# Meta-analysis of data with no standard deviation

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, kruskal-wallis-test

I am carrying out a Meta-analysis on the impacts of forest logging on Soil. One of the parameter which I want to investigate is the qbs-ar index, which is a index of soil biological quality. This index has not a standard deviation considering that it is obtained as the sum of the maximum scores among the samples and it is statistically treated with the kruskal-Wallis test. How is it possible to do a Meta-analysis of such data considering that it is not possible to calculate the typical Response ratio effect size being lacking the standard deviation?
Thank you...

Comment: You may not include data from such a trial in the primary analysis. However, you could perform sensitivity analyses applying hypothetical SD to this trial (eg the largest one from other more completely reported trials)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this is not the topic. This index qbs-ar is one of the parameter that I want to investigate, I have also other ones but for these there is the standard deviation and so everything works fine. This qbs-ar index is by itself something which can not have standard deviation. So my question is if there is a way to carry out a Meta-analysis on this parameter. Maybe with an effect size which is not the natural log of the response ratio.

Comment: I see your point... A possible approach could be to weight the effect size for the sample size (eg as it is or after logarithm transformation). In this way a qbs-ar estimate from a small study would be given less emphasis...